# Easy way to override toString() in Java

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I have a java bean with many fields. I have know how to override `toString()` using StringBuilder and directly using field names. Is there any way to do it in better way like, without field names?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: this bean is already implemented in my product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I often use Apache Common Lang's [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) like so:

```
public String toString() {
   return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

This uses reflection to generate a `toString` for the object in question.

Comment: Just beware that the performance overhead of that can be quite immense. If it's rarely used or for debugging purposes, it's perfect though.

Comment: Can this be used in Android? my IDE cannot find it, when I try to import `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Common have a [`ToStringBuilder` class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) that uses reflection to create a nice `toString` result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to do the same either explicitly or by using a helper class such as the one provided [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html). I would assume that reflection has an overhead to using the field names directly.